# SQL: selecting the second-lowest value (via subquery) with GROUP BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, correlated-subquery

Given a database of decimal values, grouped into locations ...

```
CREATE TABLE ItemPrices
    (`Company` varchar(11), `LocationID` char(5), `ProductLevel` varchar(11), `LowPrice` decimal(5,2))
;

INSERT INTO ItemPrices
    (`Company`, `LocationID`, `LowPrice`)
VALUES
    ('Company 1', 10001, 100.00),
    ('Company 2', 10001, 200.00),
    ('Company 3', 10001, 300.00),
    ('Company 4', 10001, 400.00),
    ('Company 1', 10002, 10.00),
    ('Company 2', 10002, NULL),
    ('Company 3', 10002, 30.00),
    ('Company 4', 10002, 40.00)
;
```

It's easy to select the lowest value for a location:

```
SELECT LocationID,min(LowPrice) FROM ItemPrices GROUP BY LocationID;

LOCATIONID  MIN(LOWPRICE)
10001       100
10002       10
```

But using a subquery to filter out the lowest value and return the next lowest value doesn't work as expected:

```
SELECT LocationID,min(LowPrice) FROM ItemPrices
WHERE LowPrice >
(SELECT min(LowPrice)
    FROM ItemPrices)
GROUP BY LocationID;

LOCATIONID  MIN(LOWPRICE)
10001       100
10002       30
```

The result should show LocationID 10001's second-lowest price as 200, not 100.

Seems the subquery is just returning the lowest `LowPrice` (10) in all cases. The proper logic would be to find the lowest price for that particular `LocationID` (100), then find a larger value for that `LocationID` (200) and return that larger value.

How can I make the subquery aware that it should be evaluating only a subset of the prices?

Just putting a `GROUP BY` in there (`LowPrice > (SELECT min(LowPrice) FROM ItemPrices GROUP BY LocationID)`) tells me `Subquery returns more than 1 row` -- right, of course, it returns one row for every `LocationID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In typing in this question, I have hit on the idea that I need a correlated subquery. The first step is to alias the table `ItemPrices`. I'm using `i` for the outer query and `s` for the subquery.

```
SELECT i.LocationID,min(LowPrice) FROM ItemPrices i
WHERE
LowPrice >
(SELECT min(LowPrice)
 FROM ItemPrices s
WHERE i.LocationID = s.LocationID)
GROUP BY LocationID;
```

Let's run it!

```
LOCATIONID  MIN(LOWPRICE)
10001       200
10002       30
```

Looking good! What you think?

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/341ce/5

Answer (score 0):

The issue in using > would be a case where the cheapest price is tied for two or more locations. So perhaps the desired behavior would be to show the second cheapest even if that is technically the same price as the first, but instead this would show the third cheapest.

Another solution is to create a temporary table and fill it with the cheapest locations and then left joining them and removing all matched records.

```
#create a temp table to hold the cheapest
create temporary table t (ID int, MINPRICE int, LOCATIONID int);

#fill it with the very cheapest prices
insert into t select ID, min(LOWPRICE) as MINPRICE, LOCATIONID from `ItemPrices` group by LOCATIONID;

#select the second cheapest records by EXCLUDING the very cheapest
select ItemPrices.ID, min(ItemPrices.LOWPRICE) as MINPRICE, ItemPrices.LOCATIONID 
from ItemPrices
left join t 
       on t.ID = ItemPrices.ID
where t.ID is null
group by LOCATIONID;
```

Another advantage of this method is that it is easier to expand to pull the Nth cheapest by iterating the results into the temporary table for n-1 times and then writing out the last iteration as the result.

disclaimer: I didn't check the example code for syntax, but the theory is sound. I ran into this on a table with >50M records and it is fast and accurate.